# Active modal view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hy,
I want to edit some data using modal view. So I make the code for modal view and I am unable to edit input area.

[image: You can see the image with issue here.]

The code for my modal is:

```html
<?php
    $edit_data      =   $this->db->get_where('disertatie' , array('disertatie_id' => $param2) )->result_array();
    foreach ( $edit_data as $row):
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" data-collapsed="0">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title" >
                    <i class="entypo-plus-circled"></i>
                    <?php echo get_phrase('editare_nota_student');?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php echo form_open(site_url('teacher/update_disertatie/do_update/'.$row['disertatie_id']) , array('class' => 'form-horizontal form-groups-bordered validate','target'=>'_top'));?>

            <div class="form-group">
        .......................
        <script type="text/javascript">

            // ajax form plugin calls at each modal loading,
            $(document).ready(function() {

                // SelectBoxIt Dropdown replacement
                if($.isFunction($.fn.selectBoxIt))
                {
                    $("select.selectboxit").each(function(i, el)
                    {
                        var $this = $(el),
                            opts = {
                                showFirstOption: attrDefault($this, 'first-option', true),
                                'native': attrDefault($this, 'native', false),
                                defaultText: attrDefault($this, 'text', ''),
                            };

                        $this.addClass('visible');
                        $this.selectBoxIt(opts);
                    });
                }
            });

          </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems me error with the css code.

Adjust the `z-index` in the modal.

.modal-dialog, .modal-content { z-index: 99999; }

This happen when the `backdrop` is on the front off page.